# Saxon: result-document() function fails without error message

Tags: batch-file, xslt, saxon

I'm calling Saxon (9.6 HE) from a batch file:

```
Transform -t -s:"in.xml" -xsl:"ChangeFileName.xsl" -o:"changefilename.txt" 1>>convert.log 2>&1
```

The command `1>>convert.log 2>&1` sends Saxon's standard error output to the file `convert.log`.

Transform calls an XSLT that outputs 2 text files:

```
 <xsl:template match="manual">
         <xsl:result-document method="text" href="version.txt">
                 <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/manual/bookVariables/Variable[@Name='USR_Manual_Version']/@Value"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
         </xsl:result-document>  
         <xsl:result-document method="text" href="state.txt">
              <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/manual/bookVariables/Variable[@Name='USR_Manual_State']/@Value"/>
         </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:template>
```

This works when I run the transformation from my own user account, but fails when I use a different account: the text files `state.txt` and `version.txt` are not created.

I'm trying to troubleshoot this, but Saxon does not output any error message. My log file just contains

```
Writing to file:/Z:/version.txt
```

with no indication that the write has failed or why it's failed.

Worse, when I run the Transform command directly from a command line window, it succeeds.

How can I get more detailed error information out of Saxon?

Comment: So that XSLT tries to create two text files and the log (to which the `-t` option generated output like "Writing to ..." goes) only says "Writing to file:/Z:/version.txt" but not "Writing to file:/Z:/state.txt"? And none of the two files is created? Is there any security setting preventing that "different" account from writing to files on device `Z:`?

Comment: The log has entries for both files. The user has write access to Z:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky. It's unlikely you'll get any more information out of Saxon, because Saxon probably isn't aware that the files haven't been successfully written. Usually with problems like this, the files actually exist, but they aren't where you expect them.

One suggestion: try running with the -T option. The resulting trace should tell you whether the transformation ran to (apparently successful) completion, or whether it broke off prematurely at some stage.

Another suggestion: experiment with using absolute URIs (e.g. file:///x/y/z.txt) in the href attribute.

I've forgotten most of what I once knew about Windows file systems, but is there any possibility that under the account that fails, drive letter Z is mapped to somewhere unexpected?

Comment: the drive letter could be the problem; I'l look into that.

Comment: I found a mismatch: the batchfile was called from an UNC path, while the XSLT transformation tries to write to drive letter Z: When I replace the UNC path with a drive letter, the files are written correctly. I'll do some more tests to see if I can get it to work with UNC paths.

Comment: The mapping of UNC paths to URIs is notoriously fickle (it's poorly defined and I don't think Java always gives the same result as .NET). Remember that XSLT deals with URIs.